# C# fill gridview from Datatable using ajax

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

<sup>First I want to specify that I am very new in programming, especially in c#.</sup>

I have a GridView filled with data from dataTable. It's hidden until I click on a button to display the Gridview. This works fine, but everytime I click the button the page reloads, and it takes like 2 seconds for the gridview to display. I am thinking about using Ajax, but my first question is, is there another way without using ajax ?

If there is not I found some tutos using ajax:

- [bind gridview using jquery json ajaxcall in aspnet](http://www.dotnetspan.com/2015/02/bind-gridview-using-jquery-json-ajaxcall-in-aspnet.html)
- [bind data to gridview with jquery json asp net](http://www.codescratcher.com/jquery/bind-data-to-gridview-with-jquery-json-asp-net/)
- [Bind Gridview using AJAX](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/775585/Bind-Gridview-using-AJAX)

But they all are "creating" columns and rows, isn't it another way simpler than creating all the columns one by one ?

My code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

protected void Populate()
{
    string strSql = @"SELECT CAST(ID as VarChar(50)) ID, Aggregation, DateDerniereSolution, DateDescription, DerniereSolution, DescriptionDemande, FileDeTraitement, NomContact, Numero, SousRubrique, TitreDemande
                    FROM DBTable WHERE 1=1";

    DataTable DTDeskCache = DataBaseCacheDigitalHepDeskConnection.SqlDataTable(strSql, "DataBaseName");

    gvData.DataSource = DTDeskCache;
    gvData.DataBind();  
}


protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Populate();
}
```

Here is how I connect to my Db, and fill the gridView. For the connection I am using this :`using DDesk.DataBaseConnection;`, `DataBaseConnection` is a folder with files with all information needed to make the connection.

`DataBaseCacheDigitalHepDeskConnection` is the file used to make the connection and `.SqlDataTable` is a public static DataTable called from this file (I explain that because lot's of people where annoying not knowing what it was, hope that was clear).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you put `WHERE 1=1` inside all your queries?

Comment: Here I forgot to delete it, but last time, my queries with concatenation wasn't working without it, someone explained to me that I had to keep this one true all the time (hard to explain it was in french..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of asp update panel.
below is the link to msdn

[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, going to try this !

Comment: Thx for your help it works fine but it takes 8 seconds for the gridview to display, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Update panel i mentioned will help you to avoid complete reloading of the page. The 8 seconds your talking about might be due to the volume of data you are trying to query.